# std::inner_product to calculate the standard deviation of a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, compiler-errors, numeric, cmath

I'm trying to create a function to calculate the standard deviation.
I tried using `std::inner_product` and lambda expressions for op1 and op2 of inner_product to modify the operations of the `std::inner_product` function.

Unfortunately I'm getting a compiler error when calling the function in the main loop:

```
error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from "std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>" in "std::vector<std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>,std::allocator<std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>>> &"
```

This is my code:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>

float stdfunc(std::vector<float> const & invector) {
   float mean = std::accumulate(invector.begin(), invector.end(), 0.0) / invector.size();

   float sq_sum = std::inner_product(invector.begin(), invector.end(), invector.begin(), 0.0,
   [](float const & x, float const & y) {return x+y;},
   [mean](float const & x, float const & y) {return (x-mean)*(y-mean);});

   return std::sqrt(sq_sum / (invector.size() - 1));
}
```

Call in main:

```
int main(){
std::vector<float> testv {6,3,2,9,11,44,20};
float stdw = stdfunc(testv);
std::cout << "Standardabw: " << stdw << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Show the full error message.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow unfortunately my compiler shows the messages in my native language I can translate it if you want: 
```error C2664: "float stdfunc(std::vector<std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>,std::allocator<std::vector<float 
,std::allocator<float>>>> &)" : Konvertierung von Argument 1 von "std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>" in "std::vector<std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>,std::allocator<std::vector<float,std 
::allocator<float>>>> &" nicht möglich
```

Comment: The problem is at the call site. We need the code that calls this function and the definition of the variable that is passed to it.

Comment: @shyney The initial value 0.0 has the type double. Change it to 0.0f.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow if you mean the init value of the accumulator I've changed it to 0.0f on both calls and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @shyney Show the function declaration. The function declaration can differ from the function definition.

Comment: The error message in your comment shows `stdfunc` taking a vector of vectors of float, but the example code in your question has it taking a vector of float.  Have you shown the correct code?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow oh man Im so stupid thank you so much my function declaration at the top of my main function had sitll std::vector<std::vector<float>> as input parameter because I first testet it with a 2D vector thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that the type of the argument that is `std::vector<float>`

```
std::vector<float> testv {6,3,2,9,11,44,20};
float stdw = stdfunc(testv);
```

does not correspond to the type of the function parameter that is `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.

So check the function declaration. It is not excluded that the function declaration and the functions definition can differ.

Comment: Do you also know how I can iterate through each column of a 2D vector to calculate the standard deviation with inner_product the same way as I did with the 1D vector?

Comment: @shyney You can use within the function the range-based for loop for the outer vector and then for inner vectors apply your algorithms